# How to calculate skewness from frequency table in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to calculate skewness in excel from a table in which one column is an argument and second one is a number of this argument. Unfortunately, the excel formula is only for one list of data...

Can you help me?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that there is a direct way to do this, so here's a workaround.

You can convert a frequency table into a raw list as seen here:

https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1078924-turning-frequency-tables-into-raw-data.html

(Main content duplicated below in case the link breaks in the future:)

```
Row\Col A     B    C       D
1       Type  Qty  Helper  Formula
2       Ford  1    0       C2 := SUM(B1:C1)
3       Audi  5    1
4       BMW   3    6
5                  9
6
7       Ford               A7 := INDEX(A$2:A$5, MATCH(ROWS(A$7:A7) - 1, $C$2:$C$5)) & ""
8       Audi
9       Audi
10      Audi
11      Audi
12      Audi
13      BMW
14      BMW
15      BMW
16
```

Then use the `SKEW` function on `A7:A15`.